# why Window().setWindowAnimations() not work in Android 7.0;

Tags: android, android-animation, android-windowmanager

I try to add anim to my app ,but it is not work in Android 7.0 .I can not find the reason . I use the first answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174042/how-to-switch-themes-night-mode-without-restarting-the-activity), it works on Android 6.0.
this is my code:

```
 <style name="anim">
 <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
 <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
 </style>
 getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.anim);
 recreate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 7.0 change the impl

Android SDK 23

```
mMainThread.requestRelaunchActivity(mToken, null, null, 0, false, null, null, false);
```

Android SDK 24

```
 mMainThread.requestRelaunchActivity(mToken, null, null, 0, false, null, null, false,
            false /* preserveWindow */);
```

it will not reuse `window`