# Setting android theme to follow system does not change to current system theme

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

In the settings of my app i have it so that you are able to switch the theme off the app between Light, Dark and following the system. Switching between them is fine and i have that all setup however when switching to follow system from one of the other themes it does not change to the systems theme if the theme before was different to the system.

I am using this code to switch the theme:

```
        {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
            string selectedSpinnerItem = spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
            string chosenTheme = prefs.GetString("theme", "Light");

            if (selectedSpinnerItem != chosenTheme)
            {
                switch (selectedSpinnerItem)
                {
                    case "Light":
                        ((AppCompatActivity)Activity).Delegate.SetLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo);
                        prefs.Edit().PutString("theme", "Light").Commit();
                        break;
                    case "Dark":
                        ((AppCompatActivity)Activity).Delegate.SetLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightYes);
                        prefs.Edit().PutString("theme", "Dark").Commit();
                        break;
                    case "System Preference":
                        ((AppCompatActivity)Activity).Delegate.SetLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightFollowSystem);
                        prefs.Edit().PutString("theme", "System Preference").Commit();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

This takes place in a fragment of my main activity.

Answer (score 1):

Do you change your theme to extend from one of the `DayNight` variants, and then call one method to enable the feature ?

For example:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">

   .......
</style>
```

If you’re using `Material Design Components` (and I recommend you to do so), then you can also use the `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` theme from their v1.1.0 release.

And you should know the two methods.

[setDefaultNightMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate#setDefaultNightMode(int))

The method is static so you can call it at any time. The value you set is **not** persisted across process starts though, therefore you need to set it every time your app process is started. I recommend setting it in your application class (if you have one)

like so:

```
[Application]
class MyApplication:Application
{
    public MyApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip) : base(handle, ownerShip)
    {
    }
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode =
       AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightFollowSystem;
    }
}
```

[setLocalNightMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate#setLocalNightMode(int))

Setting DayNight for a single Activity.

You can override the default value in each component with a call to its `AppCompatDelegate`’s `setLocalNightMode()`. This is handy when you know that only some components should use the DayNight functionality, or for development so that you don’t have to sit and wait for night to fall to test your layout.
Using this method in every Activity is now an anti-pattern, and you should move to using `setDefaultNightMode()` instead.

the more you could look [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94)

**Update**:

I checked the source code and it seems that it miss the handling when the mode is `ModeNightFollowSystem`

```
public void setLocalNightMode(int mode) {
    switch(mode) {
    case -1:
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
        if (this.mLocalNightMode != mode) {
            this.mLocalNightMode = mode;
            if (this.mApplyDayNightCalled) {
                this.applyDayNight();
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        Log.i("AppCompatDelegate", "setLocalNightMode() called with an unknown mode");
    }
```

if `mLocalNightMode = -1` (ModeNightFollowSystem),and when we call `Delegate.SetLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightFollowSystem);`(-1) it will go out.

So I find a workaround,get the Current night mode first,then set it directly

```
case "System Preference":
     UiModeManager uiManager = (UiModeManager)GetSystemService(UiModeService);
     int mode = (int)uiManager.NightMode;
     Delegate.SetLocalNightMode(mode);
     prefs.Edit().PutString("theme", "System Preference").Commit();
   break;
```

Comment: Yes i have implemented day night theme into my styles, however the set default night mode that you described does not change the theme off my application at all compared to the local night mode. Even if i add an activity recreat afterwards, siwtching to light and dark works fine using the spinner but switching to follow system does not switch if the prior app theme and OS theme is different...

Comment: Could you share a simplified project ?

Comment: Please see my edited comment and i can send over the code i am using for the spinner to switch theme.

Comment: i have now added my current spinner code to my question along with a video of the behaviour

Comment: @euandeas ok,i see,i will check and then give you a reply later

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: i have been looking around and cant find much

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i have found out that simply migrating to androidx fixed the bug!